# File not visible after writing android

Tags: android, file-io, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write some json data to the file, below is what i have tried.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("name", "mkyong.com");
    } catch (JSONException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        obj.put("age", new Integer(100));
    } catch (JSONException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("msg 1");
    list.add("msg 2");
    list.add("msg 3");

    try {
        obj.put("messages", list);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream fs;
    String filename = "Sample.json";
    try {
        fs = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        fs.write(obj.toString().getBytes());
        fs.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I dont get any errors though, but the file created is not visible. Should i have to read it to verify its written properly?? It would be of great help if i can see the created file in the src folder since i write many stuff, its easy to validate.

Comment: Not visible where-  in the file explorer, or to the application?  If its just to the file explorer, remember that files are kept by default in a directory hidden to all other applications, including file explorers.

Comment: In the file explorer, thanks for the reply, so there is no way tat i can access it to see the contents??

Comment: Edit: I figured out its present in the file explorer, but can i read it?

Comment: If you want to read this file from `File Explorer'' just click on your file and there is an option push file at your right hand side click and save your file and read it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably lame, but we can locate the file in the DDMS perspective and pull out tag will will be visible!! From there, we can pull it out and view it from the local computer!!

Comment: ya you can see by this only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
String filename = "Sample.txt";
```

instead of

```
String filename = "Sample.json";
```